# BindingsEndpoint kafka Stream spring boot

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

i guess . It's working fine on local pc but on cloud k8s it's not working please help, thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQrXT.png)

'org.springframework.cloud.stream.endpoint.BindingsEndpoint' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.endpoint.BindingsEndpoint' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but in my case, this fixed the issue.

```
    @Bean
    public BindingsEndpoint bindingsEndpoint(List<InputBindingLifecycle> inputBindings,
                                         List<OutputBindingLifecycle> outputBindings) {
            return new BindingsEndpoint(new BindingsLifecycleController(inputBindings, outputBindings));
    }
```